# How to Import XML Data in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

I have xml data that I am trying to import my database. I am attempting to use the nokogiri gem. I have written a file called xml_data.rb. When I run `>ruby xml_data.rb` on the command line, I recieve the following error:

> xml_data.rb:8:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Job (NameError)
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in`block in each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in`each'
>           from xml_data.rb:7:in `'

I'm not sure I understand how to do this properly. Below is the xml_data.rb file:

```
require 'nokogiri'

OLD_DATA = 'data/old_data.xml'

doc = File.open(OLD_DATA) {|f| Nokogiri::XML(f)}

doc.css('request').each do |node|
    Job.create(
        :last_name => node['name'],
        :telephone => node['phone'],
        :street_address => node['address'],
        :city => node['city'],
        :state => node['state'],
        :zip => node['zip'],
        :email => node['email'],
        :au_chog => node['chogAu'],
        :person_type => node['affil'],
        :research_use => node['use'],
        :subject => node['subject'],
        :notes => node['note'],
        :start_date => node['startDate'],
        :end_date => node['addDate'],
        :complete => true,
        :time_spend => node['hours']
    )
end
```

Ruby: v2.3.3
Rails: v5.0.1

**UPDATE**

I rewrote this code to be a rake task. However, I've not done this. When I run the task I get several syntax errors that have to do with the XML syntax, which is correct. Below is the updated code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

namespace :db do
  namespace :seed do

    desc 'Add old data to database'
    task :import_data => :environment do


        OLD_DATA = "#{Rails.root}/lib/assets/data/old_data.xml"

        doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(OLD_DATA)) do |config|
            config.options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT
        end

        doc.css("request").each do |node|
            Job.create(
                :last_name => node['name'],
                :telephone => node['phone'],
                :street_address => node['address'],
                :city => node['city'],
                :state => node['state'],
                :zip => node['zip'],
                :email => node['email'],
                :au_chog => node["chogAu"],
                :person_type => node['affil'],
                :research_use => node['use'],
                :subject => node['subject'],
                :notes => node['note'],
                :start_date => node['startDate'],
                :end_date => node['addDate'],
                :complete => true,
                :time_spend => node['hours']
            )
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as a rake task.

```
require 'nokogiri'

namespace :db do
    namespace :seed do

        desc 'Add old data to database'
        task :import_data => :environment do

            OLD_DATA = "#{Rails.root}/lib/assets/data/old_data.xml"

            doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(OLD_DATA)) do |config|
                config.options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT
            end

            doc.css("request").each do |node|
                Job.create(
                    :last_name => node['name'],
                    :telephone => node['phone'],
                    :street_address => node['address'],
                    :city => node['city'],
                    :state => node['state'],
                    :zip => node['zip'],
                    :email => node['email'],
                    :au_chog => node["chogAu"],
                    :person_type => node['affil'],
                    :research_use => node['use'],
                    :subject => node['subject'],
                    :notes => node['note'],
                    :start_date => node['startDate'],
                    :end_date => node['addDate'],
                    :complete => true,
                    :time_spend => node['hours']
                )
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I am not. I had a line that was causing problems. When I discovered it, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Job isn't defined since you're not actually running it inside the Rails environment.

Add

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'config/environment')
```

Comment: Ok. This is the error I'm receiving now

`C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- C:/Sites/arch_record_keeper/config/environments (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from xml_data.rb:1:in `<main>'`

Comment: Where is this file located? Is it in the rails home directory?

Comment: It is not. It is in the app's app/assets directory.

Comment: You should almost never have .rb files in app/assets. For a file like this, that's responsible for inserting data into a db, I'd recommend putting it in lib/. Or else, write it as a .rake file and put it in lib/tasks/. If it's a rake task, then when you start it up you'll have the rails environment preloaded and you won't have to go down the rabbit hole of trying to load up rails outside of the app proper.

Comment: @Glyoko I rewrote the code to be a rake task, but now I'm getting a bunch of syntax errors. I posted the code as an update.

Answer (score 0):

If your outside of rails you can try something like this.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql2', # or 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' or 'oracle_enhanced'
  host:     'localhost',
  database: 'your_database',
  username: 'your_username',
  password: 'your_password'
)

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ExampleData
  attr_reader :file

  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
  end

  def xml
    Nokogiri::XML(open(file))
  end

  def create_jobs
    xml.css('request').each do |node|
      Job.create(
        :last_name => node['name'],
        :telephone => node['phone'],
        :street_address => node['address'],
        :city => node['city'],
        :state => node['state'],
        :zip => node['zip'],
        :email => node['email'],
        :au_chog => node['chogAu'],
        :person_type => node['affil'],
        :research_use => node['use'],
        :subject => node['subject'],
        :notes => node['note'],
        :start_date => node['startDate'],
        :end_date => node['addDate'],
        :complete => true,
        :time_spend => node['hours']
    )
    end
  end


  file = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/data/old_data.xml"
  example_data = ExampleData.new(file)
  example_data.create_jobs
end
```